# how to get rid of lines in the Displacement maps

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, displacement

These lines keep appearing in my displacement maps... What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Are your maps made of pure black lines on a pure white background? I only ask because the edges look like aliased pixels somewhat. Displacement maps play best with some kind of gradient along the edges instead of harsh cutoff from black to white. How are you making (or getting) the displacement maps?

Comment: maybe pack the image ahd share your object so that we can test it? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Please provide either a .blend file or elaborate on your intended end result to help narrow down possible causes of your issue.